# Referencing an object in an array by parsing it to the function

Tags: reactjs, arrays, scroll

I want to improve my scrolling code. I have the following working code...

```
  const scrollRef = [];
  const scrollClick = (event) => {    
    console.log(scrollRef[1]);
    scrollRef[1].scrollIntoView(); 
  }
```

The above works using...

```
<button onClick={scrollClick}>Bottom Of Page</button>
```

which scrolls to ...

```
<div ref={(ref) => { scrollRef[1] = ref }}>  Bottom of page </div>
```

What I want to do is call the particular reference point in the *scrollRef[x]* array from the button instead, for example...

```
<button onClick={scrollClick[1]}>Bottom Of Page </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To strictly answer your question following your current code and logic, you could do something such as the following:

```
const scrollClick = (index) => {
  scrollRef[index].scrollIntoView(); 
}
```

With the button rendered with:

```
<button onClick={() => scrollClick(1)}>Bottom Of Page </button>
```

(Assuming `scrollClick[1]` is a typo) When passing `onClick`, you are passing a callback - if you pass a function call directly (i.e. `myFunc(someValue)` and not `() => myFunc(someValue))` then `myFunc` will executed on render - the return value of it being set as the `onClick` handler.

Comment: thanks, this sorted it. I was close but was making mistakes with the onClick part as you correctly point out.

Comment: That's great, glad to hear it helped!